# duty free from UK to EU country during transition period

Tags: uk, air-travel, eu, duty-free

I was under assumption that nothing changed during transition period but apparently. My friend flew from BHX to DUS on 25/02/2020. It was not allowed to buy any alcohol in duty-free shop except only 3 kinds of beverages... Does someone can comment on this with link to regulations in transition period? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The transition period has not changed anything yet and the allowance still stays as 10 litres, as to the beverages I’m not sure why only 3 types were allowed.